# How to execute function based on day?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have a function that is shown below that executes a function based on the hour. How can I modify it to also execute based on the day of WEEK?

```
let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour


    if(hour >= 9 && hour <= 17)
    {
        //set your image 'open image'
        println("Open")
    }
    else{
         //set your image 'close image'
        println("closed")
    }
```

Comment: @iphonic Which day would Sunday be? 1 or 7? I tried and it doest seem to work?

Comment: Look for custom calendar libraries here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=custom+calendar+swift&oq=custom+calendar+swi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.6997j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8 . It will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCalendarUnit` can be initialized with an `UInt`, so this gives you all possible components:

```
var flags = NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max)
let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: date)
let day=components.day
let hour = components.hour
```

Comment: I still need the hour component though?

Comment: I get the day of the month, how can I get the day of the week?

Comment: Use components.weekday for that.

Comment: Is Sunday equal to 1 or 7?